# Read array that is returned from a controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I get a response back from my Laravel backend when a user tries to log in. I want to read this data so it can be displayed in the front-end.

I would I target those errors that are returned?

I have this:
console.log(response.response.data.errors);
That returns:
[image: Returned values]
How would I target only the messages, in this case the one for email and for password.
In other cases it might be more or less errors.

Comment: have you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)?

Comment: Sins this is an object you can loop the object and read the data.

Comment: yes. But you can't include PHP code in a vue component under scripts

Answer (score 0):

add error.js and write condition in your controller like if username and password doesn't match with database then use:

return redirect()->back()->withErrors();

it will display errors in front-end.